# How to find common constant

Tags: numpy, math, reverse-engineering

I have a list of KIPs which are masked and i want to find the real value behind.
KPI is the number of events on a certain time t

The way the KPI is masked is by using the following logic:

1. new_KPI(t) = KPI(t) * C
2. new_KPI_2(t) = KPI_2(t) * C
3. new_KPI_3(t) = KPI_3(t) * C

The only info i have is that the real value of the KPI should be a natural number.

How can I find the C constant?

Comment: Why can't you use simple algebra to figure this out?

Comment: thanks ... any idea how to do that :)   I just have the new values  17.322,11.047, 0.5919, 0.4020, 577.729

Comment: If you don't have the original values, your problem is underdetermined.  You in essence have an equation with one known, and two unknowns.  There's an infinite number of solutions, which means there are no good ones.

Comment: Voting to close this question as it has nothing to do with programming.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with programming and is unsolvable.